# Java Ranking items in a List

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am attempting to write what seems like a very basic calculation.  However after several attempts it is still kicking my butt.

Problem to solve.  I have a `<List>StudentGrades`.  `StudentGrades` tells me who the students are and what the students `.finalPercentage()` is.  Now I want to be able to determine a students `classStanding`.  If scores look like the following:

> 100 99 98 98 98 97 96

Then rankings should look like

> 1 2 3 3 3 6 7

This is what I have tried:

```
public final class RankingUtil{
  public static Integer getClassStanding(StudentGrades studentGrades, List<StudentGrades> allStudentGrades) {
    int classRank = 0;
    BigDecimal lastScore = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal secondLastScore = null;
    Collections.sort(allStudentGrades, new Comparator<StudentGrades>() {
      public int compare(StudentGrades o1, StudentGrades o2) {
        return -o1.getFinalPercentage().compareTo(o2.getFinalPercentage());
      }
    });

    for (StudentGrades sg : allStudentGrades) {
      if (!lastScore.equals(sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved()) && lastScore.equals(secondLastScore)) {
        classRank++;
      }

      if (!lastScore.equals(sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved())) {
        classRank++;
      }

      secondLastScore = lastScore;
      lastScore = sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved();

      if (sg.equals(studentGrades)) {
        return classRank;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

I am sure its a simple mistake I am making but the problem I run into is I end up with the following ranks:

> 1 2 3 3 3 5 6

What would you recommend to keep track of the position that the individual should fall in?

Comment: you do not need `secondLastScore` just compare `lastScore` to `sg` and you are done. also you need to change from `equals` to `compareTo` when comparing `BigDecimal`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this. Basically, the `classRank` is just the position in the list, except when the score is the same as before, in this case the rank is the same as before, too. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allStudentGrades.size(); i++) {
    StudentGrades sg = allStudentGrades.get(i);
    BigDecimal newScore = sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved();
    if (lastScore.compareTo(newScore) != 0) {
        classRank = i + 1;
    }
    if (sg.equals(studentGrades)) {
        return classRank;
    }
    lastScore = newScore;
}
```

Also, you might want to cache those values in a dictionary, instead of calculating them each time anew.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with over complicating things.   Your answer worked out nicely and it did not modify what I was doing by much.  As for the Dictionary.  This calculation is only done on a list maxing out at 50 people.  The load will not be much.  The request was for it to be a real time calculation but thanks for going above and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you have all these local counters. Just sort your list and find the first match for your given studentGrade.

```
public static Integer getClassStanding(StudentGrade studentGrade, List<StudentGrade> allStudentGrades) {
    List<StudentGrade> localList = new ArrayList<>(allStudentGrades);
    Collections.sort(localList, new Comparator<StudentGrade>() {
        @Override public int compare(StudentGrade first, StudentGrade second) {
            return (second.getScore() <= first.getScore()) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < localList.size(); i++) {
        if (localList.get(i).getScore() == studentGrade.getScore())
            return i+1;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also note that I made a local copy of the list-parameter. You probably don't want to sort the list of StudentGrades for everyone outside the method scope.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work :

```
public final class RankingUtil {
    public static Integer getClassStanding(StudentGrades studentGrades, List<StudentGrades> allStudentGrades) {
        int classRank = 0;
        int rankCarryOver = 0;
        BigDecimal lastScore = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        Collections.sort(allStudentGrades, new Comparator<StudentGrades>() {
            public int compare(StudentGrades o1, StudentGrades o2) {
                return -o1.getFinalPercentage().compareTo(o2.getFinalPercentage());
            }
        });

    for (StudentGrades sg : allStudentGrades) {


        if (lastScore.compareTo(sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved()) != 0) {
            classRank++;
            classRank = classRank + rankCarryOver;
            rankCarryOver = 0;
        } else {
            rankCarryOver++;
        }

        secondLastScore = lastScore;
        lastScore = sg.getGradeSheetScoreTotalAchieved();

        if (sg.equals(studentGrades)) {
            return classRank;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}